# How can I list all installed plugins/themes/versions from CLI/API?

Tags: plugins, themes, wp-cli, wp-api, command-line

I would like to generate a simple text report for a Wordpress instance listing:

- Wordpress version
- plugins installed (version and whether enabled)
- themes and child themes installed (version and whether enabled)

I can get this information from the Dashboard, but is there a way to get it programmatically (with WP CLI, WP API or regular command line calls)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using WP CLI, you can record Wordpress version using:

```
wp core version --extra --path="$SITEPATH" > wp-report.txt
```

and append a list of plugins (with status and version):

```
wp plugin list --path="$SITEPATH" >> wp-report.txt
```

and append a list of themes (with status and version) using:

```
wp theme list --path="$SITEPATH" >> wp-report.txt
```

**Further reading:**

- https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/core/version/
- https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/plugin/list/
- https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/theme/list/

Answer (score 1):

WP CLI is probably the best for this:

WordPress Version:

```
wp core version --path="$SITEPATH" > wp-report.txt
```

List Plugins:

```
wp plugin list --path="$SITEPATH" >> wp-report.txt
```

List Themes:

```
wp theme list --path="$SITEPATH" >> wp-report.txt
```

(replacing $SITEPATH with the WordPress installation directory.)

Reference: https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/

Comment: thanks for the additional detail, I've updated my answer with these parameters